# Jupyter Lab Render button disable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter-lab, plotly-python

[image]

There is a green button call 'Render with panel ' in my 'Jupyer lab' and I'm trying to get rid of it, not sure where its come from.

**Things I've tried:**

https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-can-i-disable-an-extension-in-jupyterlab-3/9332/2
the jupyter labextension disable didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That icon comes from [the Panel Extension](https://panel.holoviz.org/index.html), 'Panel: A high-level app and dashboarding solution for Python'. It's part of their visual branding as you should see a larger version in the upper left corner [the there](https://panel.holoviz.org/index.html).

(Under 'Things I've tried:', you don't actually include the specific command you tried running.).
To try and disable it:
Did you try based on [here](https://panel.holoviz.org/getting_started/index.html) and that suggestion you highlighted under 'Things I've tried', the following?

```py
jupyter labextension disable @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz
```

According to [a Jupyter Discourse thread by another person puzzling over that icon and how to get rid of it](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/http-500-when-render-with-lumen/13163/5?u=fomightez) that should work. In fact, I just tried running that command in a terminal in a MyBinder-provided session launched from [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/holoviz/panel/v0.12.6?urlpath=lab/tree/examples) & after running it **and refreshing the browser window**, the panel icon disappeared from the bar at the top of notebooks.

You could surely get rid of it by making an environment for your Jupyter where you don't install it. And then work there.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to disable by running the 'jupyter labextension disable @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz' in the conda cmd in that envirnoment. I originally runned the "jupyter labextension disable jupyterlab_vim" since i didn't know where that green button come from or how to find which library generate that button.